# Заголовок OPTIONS при авторизации через JWT

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, angular2

Делаю два сервиса. Один - фронт на `Angular 2`. Второй - бэк на `Spring`. Авторизация сделана через `JWT`.

Проблема в том, что при отправке запроса на бэк через `postman` [все работает](http://joxi.net/krDGOLBcQXqgAp). Но вот при отправке запроса через `Angular 2` возникает [проблема](http://joxi.net/BA0Np9EUGXxvmy) с методом `OPTIONS`. `Spring` видит, что это не `POST` и почему-то не читает тело запроса.

Запрос из `angular`:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({username, password}));
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8");


    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/login`, JSON.stringify({username, password}), {headers: headers, withCredentials: true})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let token = response.json().id_token;
            if (token) {
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.json().id_token);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        });
}
```

Проверил - данные в теле запроса от `angular` уходят. В чем может быть дело и самое главное - как это поправить ?

Comment: Это поведение описано в рекомендацию w3c, ссылку на которую писал тебе в предыдущем вопросе. Там описано что клиент может послать тело в запросе options, но веб сервера игнорируют всегда это тело. Инициатором запросов options является браузер (проверка cors), и выполняются они перед post или get

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov Я это уже понял. :) Но как это знание поможет мне решить эту задачу ?

Comment: тебе это поможет настроить CORS на сервере)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае кросс-доменных запросов если заголовок Content-Type отличается от application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data или text/plain, то посылается предзапрос (preflight request). Его шлет сам браузер, а не Angular.
Так что можно либо изменить Content-Type, либо не использовать кросс-доменных запросы удалив 'http://' из 'this.url', либо настроить spring чтобы он корректно обрабатывал preflight request.

Comment: Поменял обращение к сервису на такое:

Comment: `let headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/login`, JSON.stringify({username, password}), { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let token = response.json().id_token;
                if (token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.json().id_token);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
                // return true;
            });`

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.